# How to fix Index value 1 is out of range. Can't get variable to pass properly through twitter get status function

Tags: python, excel, indexing, twitter, tweepy

Appended variable not working with get status to retrieve tweet texts

---

I have a list of tweets id's, probably around 50,000 in an excel file on my computer. I want to create a piece of code that will allow me to extract the text from the tweets so I can then analyse...

I have created a variable 'tweetref' to store the tweet id's that I can pass to get status etc to get the tweet text. I am told many of these tweets might not exist anymore and I can't tell which one from the id which is why I have done 'pass' on the except, hoping to ignore all the fails and just get the ones that work. Using firehose api to gather is too expensive for me.

It didn't spit out any text even though manually replacing tweetref' in 'tweet = api.get_status(tweetref)' - with the commented number below (38387433561128960), prints an actual tweet

I tried to get the 2nd index from tweet ref which resulted in a 'list index out of range' - not sure why since there should by over twenty variables in the list. Not sure what i've done wrong?

EDIT - Have changed

"tweetref.append(datalist[30:50])"

to

"tweetref.extend(datalist[30:50])"

This helpfully results in all ID's becoming individual elements in "tweetref" and allows me to call on indexes properly. However, despite this, the second "for" loop with get status still isn't printing any text from the tweets

```
# Import twitter related packages
import json
import tweepy

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#import request style packages

import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

# Import excel related packages

import xlrd
import openpyxl

# Import visualisation packages

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Store OAuth authentication credentials in relevant variables
access_token = "private"
access_token_secret = "private"

consumer_key = "private"
consumer_secret = "private"

# Pass OAuth details to tweepy's OAuth handler

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("private", "private")
auth.set_access_token("private", "private")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Read and write to excel

dataFileUrl = R"C:/Users/ebaba/Desktop/algeria1.xlsx"


# Create pandas data frame out of Tweet ID Column of file

data = pd.read_excel(dataFileUrl, usecols = ['Tweet'])

# Convert data frame into a list

datalist = data.values.tolist()

tweetref = []

for t in range (0,20):

    tweetref.append(datalist[30:50])

    print(tweetref[1])

for i in range (0,1):

     try:

        tweet = api.get_status(tweetref)

#38387433561128960 - Example Working Tweet - N.44

        print(tweet.text)

     except:

        pass




Expected result would include the tweet 

'RT @mattseaton: Another fascinating dispatch from inside the pro-democracy movement in Algiers, from Karima Bennoune

which is in the datalist[30:50] range

Actual Result

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ebaba\Desktop\example6.py", line 56, in <module>
    print(tweetref[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 16.902s]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time through this `for` loop:

```
tweetref = []
for t in range (0,20):
    tweetref.append(datalist[30:50])
    print(tweetref[1])
```

your code appends a list to `tweetref` that was previously empty. So that list of (maybe) 20 items becomes element 0 of `tweetref`. That is why you get index out of range when your code tries to access `tweetref[1]`.

If you want all (maybe) 20 elements from `datalist` to become individual elements of `tweetref` then you need to do one of

```
    tweetref.extend(datalist[30:50])
```

or

```
    tweetref += datalist[30:50]
```

Appending a list to the previously empty `tweetref` results in a list with *one* element which is itself a list of (maybe) 20 elements.